# posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test not found in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to run posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(x=movt$numb, g=movt$EDgroups, "bonferroni") but it keeps giving the error message " could not find function "posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test". Please any ideas on the solution as this keeps happening despite installing PMCMRplus

Comment: To use a function from a package, you need to install it (once) and then load it (each session you want to use it in). Try `library(PMCMRplus)` and then your code.